# Why does Atom fail to report an identical ID error?

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

I have Atom and am working on some HTML & CSS code. I have installed some plugins, such as CSSLint. But when I do this for example:

```
<h1 id="id1">...</h1>  <p id="id1">...</p>
```

It fails to report it as an error. Do you know why?

Comment: Duplicate IDs in HTML isn't a CSS issue, it's an HTML issue. Do you have an HTML linter?

Comment: Try with this one [linter-htmlhint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-htmlhint)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I installed linter-htmlhint and linter-htmllint but the problem still remains :(